# Why can't product weight be displayed on a category page while other attributes can?

Tags: magento2.3, custom, product-view

I'm trying to display the product weight inside the category pages next to the price. I can display product name, price, id, url, etc, but not weight!

To achieve this I overrode final_price.phtml and added the following lines:

```
$_product = $finalPriceModel->getProduct();
echo $_product->getData('price'); // This works fine
echo $_product->getData('weight'); // This does not work!
```

The weight shows up in the product page, but not in the category page (product list/collection). While the price, name, url, ... all show up on both the product page and the category pages! Why doesn't this code display the weight for each product in the categories?

Comment: you need to change the store front properties for the weight attribute so that it is visible in catalog / product listings.

Comment: @paj Thank you so much! That solved the problem.